# Receiving a SIGABRT when accessing NSDictionary

Tags: ios, ios4, plist, nsdictionary, sigabrt

When using a NSDictionary that navigates to a PLIST I keep on getting an SIGABRT error,

```
**2011-09-26 18:31:01.740 AlarmAppiPhone[3126:10d03] -[__NSCFArray _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5cb5090
2011-09-26 18:31:01.742 AlarmAppiPhone[3126:10d03] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5cb5090'**
```

at this line, `editLabelTextField.text = [alarm objectForKey:ROOT_KEY];` I don't know why I am getting this. The alarm is a NSDictionary and it uses object for key to navigate to a key which I have declared like this, `#define ROOT_KEY @"Root"`. I defined it in another file. The plist looks somewhat like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>alarm1</string>
            <key>time</key>
            <date>2011-09-03T07:24:20Z</date>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>alarm2</string>
            <key>time</key>
            <string>2011-09-03T07:24:14Z</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Which exact information do you want to place in `editLabelTextField.text`?

Comment: In my plist I have a "label" key which is a string, I want to take that and place it in my textfield.

Comment: And which of the `labels` do you want? They’re inside an array and your example shows more than one.

Comment: I want it for each selected cell, like this. User taps cell and it goes to a new view and in a textField it displays the cell label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[alarm objectForKey:@"Root"]` returns an `NSArray`, which you're trying to assign to a property which expects an `NSString`. (`_isNaturallyRTL` is an iOS-specific, private function of `NSString`.)

I assume you're trying to get to the `label`. Structurally, such an access would look like this (your variable `alarm` should probably be called `alarmPlist`):

```
NSArray *alarms = [alarmPlist objectForKey:@"Root"];
NSDictionary *alarm = [alarms objectAtIndex:0];
editLabelTextField.text = [alarm objectForKey:@"label"];
```

Replace the `0` with a different index to access a different alarm.

Comment: Thanks I got it almost, but I want the objectAtIndex:0 to return indexPath.row. So I want it to be like this, User taps cell in another view and the next view (this one) get's the label for the indexPath.row from the other view.

Comment: Then replace `0` with `indexPath.row`.

Comment: But will it find the selected row from the other view?

Comment: I tried it 10 minutes ago and it just returned alarm1 for all the cells.

Comment: That depends on a) where you get this `indexPath` from, and b) if the difference between alarms is in the row or in the section. You might want to do some sort of `NSLog(@"indexPath: section %d row %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);` to find out its value.

Comment: Output for log, indexPath: section 0 row 0. But how do I access the previous view's indexPath.row?

Comment: I'd assume it's `[thePreviousView indexPathForSelectedRow]`, but it depends heavily on your view hierarchy and what function you are doing this in. Also, **where did you get the logged `indexPath` from**, if it's not the one you need?

Comment: I tried [thePreviousView indexPathForSelectedRow] with my view (it didn't work), but I don't understand the logging indexPath from.